# Gravity not affecting the Scene

Tags: modeling, modifiers, physics, collision, cell-fracture

I have a proj on uni to simulate an asteroid clashing on to another asteroid and shattering. I already have the collisions, cell fracturing of the shattering asteroid, animations, and gravity set to 0 (more on this) but the problem is that the fractured "rocks" shatter too fast.
I can send in my .blend file if you would like to see it because I don't know how to describe this situation as much as I can

[image: Field Weights]

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the *Speed* value. Or bake the simulation and then scale the keyframes in the *Dopesheet*, or use the *Time Stretching* to slow down the animation.

[image]